# Conditional Join and Then Save Table

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables that share the fields: ID, Full Name, DoB.
The second table has NA's for ID so I will have to join by Full Name and DoB.
Something like:

```
Select * from table1 t1
     left outer join  table2 t2
       on  t1.mrn = t2.mrn
       and (t1.mrn is null 
             and t1.dob = t2.dob
             and t1.fullname = t2.fullname)
```

or

```
Select * 
 from table1 left outer join table2
        on  table1.mrn = table2.mrn
        and if table1.mrn is null 
           then (sqltest1.fullname= sqltest2.fullname
              and sqltest1.dob = sqltest2.dob)
```

Not sure how to use case when to create a conditional statement for when there is a null in ID then I want sql to use full name and DOB to make the join.

Furthermore save this query as a new table.

PS: I wrote this in R using sqldf to practice sql. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Join predicates are boolean expressions.  `a=b AND c=d` doesn't mean `include results where a=b and also results where c=d` it means `give me results where a=b and c=d at the same time`.  Those boolean expressions are evaluated on a row by row basis.  So, as per an answer below; you need `(mrn's match) OR (names match AND dobs match)`

Answer (score 1):

well, you can do this without or with  checking mrn . but either way you need to use OR :

```
Select * from table1 t1
     left outer join  table2 t2
       on  t1.mrn = t2.mrn
       or (t1.dob = t2.dob and t1.fullname = t2.fullname)
```

or :

```
Select * from table1 t1
     left outer join  table2 t2
       on  t1.mrn = t2.mrn
       or (t1.mrn is null and t1.dob = t2.dob  and t1.fullname = t2.fullname)
```

to make a new table using this query above :

```
select * 
into NewTableName
from table1 t1
     left outer join  table2 t2
       on  t1.mrn = t2.mrn
       or (t1.dob = t2.dob and t1.fullname = t2.fullname)
```

Comment: Ah okay, thank you. And how would I save this query as a new table. (sorry my background is in R so im used to just using as.data.frame outside the query).

Comment: @NaomiTinga . . . You would use `create table as` or the equivalent for whatever database you are using.

Comment: @NaomiTinga as Gordon mentioned , depends on the database , you can use 'create table as` or  query I added to the answer